# SQL Server - calculate age in day, month, year in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have found a couple of examples that have helped me to break this down, however none that can be used on a table of data.

I have a list of names and dates in a table, and **I want to calculate how old each person in in terms of the day, month and year from today**, for example:

```
   Name          DOB        Years      Months      Days
Joe Bloggs     01/10/2012     4          0         11
Steven Wright  29/02/2004     12         7         13
```

This is the query I am currently using:

```
SELECT
Person.Name,
Person.DOB,
DATEDIFF(yy, Person.DOB, GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN (MONTH(Person.DOB) > MONTH(GETDATE())) OR (MONTH(Person.DOB) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND DAY(Person.DOB) > DAY(GETDATE())) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Years,
DATEDIFF(m, Person.DOB, GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN DAY(Person.DOB) > DAY(GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Months,
DATEDIFF(d, Person.DOB, GETDATE()) AS Days
FROM Person
Where DOB IS NOT NULL
```

This will display the following for Joe Bloggs from the SQL Query above:

```
   Name            DOB        Years      Months      Days
Joe Bloggs      01/10/2012      4          48        1472
```

Basically what is happening is the years aren't being deducted from the months, and so on.. so this is the total days, total months and total years, instead of them breaking down as shown above.

**How can I amend the above query to get this to work using a table of data called `Family`, with the fields `Name` and `DOB`?**

Comment: Watch out for leap year issues. Add more test data, to make things more complex!

Comment: Get the `Datepart` of `Person.DOB` and `GETDATE()` in the DATEDIFF

Comment: ahh I haven't thought that far ahead  yet, ill add an example above to include that

Comment: DATEDIFF(YYYY, DATEPART(YEAR, StartDate), GETDATE()) this gives me the year as either 111 or 110

Comment: For months you could use the mod function. `datediff(MM, dob, getdate()) % 12 as Months`

Comment: I have a vague memory I have seen this problem before. Search SO one or two months back.

Comment: ok will do that now

Comment: thankyou all for the answers and help, most appreciated, I have plenty of ways to get this to work now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have at TVF which may look like overkill, but it is very fast and accurate

```
Declare @YourTable Table (Name varchar(25),DOB Date)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('Joe Bloggs'   ,'2012-10-01'),
('Steven Wright','2004-02-29') 

Select A.*
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Date-Elapsed](A.DOB,GetDate()) B
```

Returns

```
Name            DOB         Years   Months  Days    Hours   Minutes Seconds
Joe Bloggs      2012-10-01  4       0       11      11      3       17
Steven Wright   2004-02-29  12      7       13      11      3       17
```

The UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Date-Elapsed] (@D1 DateTime,@D2 DateTime)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cteBN(N)   as (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cteRN(R)   as (Select Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL))-1 From cteBN a,cteBN b,cteBN c),
         cteYY(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(YY,R,@D1))From cteRN R Where DateAdd(YY,R,@D1)<=@D2),
         cteMM(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(MM,R,D))  From (Select Top 12 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteYY P Where DateAdd(MM,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteDD(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(DD,R,D))  From (Select Top 31 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteMM P Where DateAdd(DD,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteHH(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(HH,R,D))  From (Select Top 24 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteDD P Where DateAdd(HH,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteMI(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(MI,R,D))  From (Select Top 60 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteHH P Where DateAdd(MI,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteSS(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(SS,R,D))  From (Select Top 60 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteMI P Where DateAdd(SS,R,D)<=@D2)

    Select [Years]   = cteYY.N
          ,[Months]  = cteMM.N
          ,[Days]    = cteDD.N
          ,[Hours]   = cteHH.N
          ,[Minutes] = cteMI.N
          ,[Seconds] = cteSS.N
     From  cteYY,cteMM,cteDD,cteHH,cteMI,cteSS
)
--Max 1000 years
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Date-Elapsed] ('1964-07-29 09:35:00.000',GetDate())
```

Answer (score 2):

I TRIED some boundary conditions on this!  Seems ok so far have a go if you like.

```
declare @dob datetime = '19800229';           --date of birth
DECLARE @DAT datetime = '20160301';           --calculation date

SELECT YEAR(@DAT) - YEAR(@dob) - 
            CASE WHEN MONTH(@DAT) < MONTH(@DOB) OR MONTH(@DAT) = MONTH(@DOB) AND DAY(@DAT) < DAY(@DOB) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END YEARS,
        (YEAR(@DAT)*12 - YEAR(@dob)*12 + MONTH(@DAT) - MONTH(@dob) - 
        CASE WHEN DAY(@DAT) < DAY(@DOB) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) % 12 MONTHS,

    datediff(day,
    dateadd(month,(YEAR(@DAT)*12 - YEAR(@dob)*12 + MONTH(@DAT) - MONTH(@dob) - 
        CASE WHEN DAY(@DAT) < DAY(@DOB) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) % 12,

    dateadd(year, YEAR(@DAT) - YEAR(@dob) - 
            CASE WHEN MONTH(@DAT) < MONTH(@DOB) OR MONTH(@DAT) = MONTH(@DOB) AND DAY(@DAT) < DAY(@DOB) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ,@dob)
            ),@DAT) DAYS
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
declare @dob date = '22Aug1982'
declare @Yr int = 2016
declare @mon int = 6
declare @dom int = 13
Select @Yr - Year(@dob) - 1 + 
case when @mon > Month(@dob) then 1
     when @mon < Month(@dob) then 0
     else case when @dom >= Day(@dob) then 1 
else 0 end end
```

But I suggest you add a computed column to the table:

```
alter table Family
    add AgeYears
    as Year(getdate()) - Year(dob) - 1 +
        case when Month(getdate()) > month(dob) then 1
             when month(getdate()) < month(dob) then 0
             else case when day(getdate()) >= day(dob) then 1
         else 0 end end
```

If you also need the additional months old, and days old, then add columns for those as well:

```
alter table Family
    add AgeYears as Year(getdate()) - Year(dob) - 1 +
           case when Month(getdate()) > month(dob) then 1
                when month(getdate()) < month(dob) then 0
                else case when day(getdate()) >= day(dob) then 1
             else 0 end end,
    AgeMonths as case when Month(getdate()) >= Month(dob) 
             then Month(getdate()) - month(dob)
             else month(dob) - Month(getdate()) end,
    AgeDays as case when day(getdate()) >= day(dob) 
             then day(getdate()) - day(dob)
             else day(dob) - day(getdate()) end
```

Comment: how would this work using a select statement to fetch multiple rows of data?

Comment: using the computed column:  `Select age from Family`

Comment: wouldn't I have to update the database every day though as I want to have the months and days aswell as the years?

Comment: you mean you want the age in Years,  months and days, not just in years?

Comment: Modified the alter table to also add columns for age in Months and age in days.

Comment: ... and you don't need to update these fields, their value is not stored in the database, it is computed on the fly from the dob column every time you ask for it in a select query.

Answer (score 1):

Try Below solution, I have not tested it thorubut it may work :

```
DECLARE @DOB DATE = '1991-11-19'
SELECT  DATEDIFF(M,@DOB,GETDATE())/12 [Year],
        DATEDIFF(M,@DOB,GETDATE())%12 [Month],
        DATEDIFF(DD,
        CASE
            WHEN DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB) > GETDATE()
                THEN DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,@DOB,GETDATE())-1,@DOB)
            ELSE DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,@DOB,GETDATE()),@DOB)
        END,
        GETDATE()) [Day]
```